# Bouncy Castle OpenPGP with VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, bouncycastle, openpgp

I'm mainly posting this for anyone else that needs it since there seems to be a great lack of resources on the internet for this.  The samples I did find seemed hobbled together at best and never worked for me.  If you see or find anything wrong with this class, I'd love to know.  Note that this class is slightly modified for my particular implementation but should work fine against version 1.7 of the Bouncy Castle .Net source code.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports Org.BouncyCastle.Bcpg.OpenPgp

Public Class PgpDecrypt
    Private _mPublicKeyPath As String = "C:\MyPgpKeys\MyKey - Public.asc"
    Private _mPrivateKeyPath As String = "C:\MyPgpKeys\MyKey - Private.asc"
    Private _mPassPhrase As String = "<passwoid>"

    Public Function Decrypt(ByVal srcPath As String, ByVal dstPath As String) As Boolean
        Dim stEnc As Stream = PgpUtilities.GetDecoderStream(File.OpenRead(srcPath))
        Dim pof As New PgpObjectFactory(stEnc)
        Dim pked As PgpPublicKeyEncryptedData = Nothing

        Dim keyPrivate As PgpPrivateKey = Nothing
        For Each pked In GetEncryptedDataList(pof).GetEncryptedDataObjects
            keyPrivate = ReadPrivateKey(pked.KeyId)
            If Not keyPrivate Is Nothing Then Exit For
        Next
        If keyPrivate Is Nothing Then Return False

        Dim stDec As Stream = pked.GetDataStream(keyPrivate)
        pof = New PgpObjectFactory(stDec)
        Dim o As PgpObject = pof.NextPgpObject
        If TypeOf o Is PgpCompressedData Then
            pof = New PgpObjectFactory(DirectCast(o, PgpCompressedData).GetDataStream)
            o = pof.NextPgpObject
        End If
        While Not TypeOf o Is PgpLiteralData
            o = pof.NextPgpObject
            If o Is Nothing Then Return False
        End While
        Dim ld As PgpLiteralData = DirectCast(o, PgpLiteralData)
        Dim stOut As Stream = File.Create(dstPath)
        Dim stUnc As Stream = ld.GetInputStream
        Org.BouncyCastle.OpenPgp.Utilities.IO.Streams.PipeAll(stUnc, stOut)
        stOut.Close()

        Return True
    End Function

    Private Function GetEncryptedDataList(ByVal pof As PgpObjectFactory) As PgpEncryptedDataList
        Dim o As PgpObject = Nothing
        While Not TypeOf o Is PgpEncryptedDataList
            o = pof.NextPgpObject
            If o Is Nothing Then Return Nothing
        End While
        Return DirectCast(o, PgpEncryptedDataList)
    End Function

    Private Function ReadPublicKey(Optional ByVal useEmbedded As Boolean = False) As PgpPublicKey
        If useEmbedded Then
            Using st As Stream = Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(GetAssemblyName() & ".MyKey - Public.asc")
                Dim bundle As PgpSecretKeyRingBundle = New PgpSecretKeyRingBundle(PgpUtilities.GetDecoderStream(st))
                For Each ring As PgpPublicKeyRing In bundle.GetKeyRings
                    For Each key As PgpPublicKey In ring.GetPublicKeys
                        If key.IsEncryptionKey Then Return key
                    Next
                Next
            End Using
        Else
            Using st As Stream = File.OpenRead(_mPublicKeyPath)
                Dim bundle As PgpPublicKeyRingBundle = New PgpPublicKeyRingBundle(PgpUtilities.GetDecoderStream(st))
                For Each ring As PgpPublicKeyRing In bundle.GetKeyRings
                    For Each key As PgpPublicKey In ring.GetPublicKeys
                        If key.IsEncryptionKey Then Return key
                    Next
                Next
            End Using
        End If

        Return Nothing
    End Function

    Private Function ReadSecretKey(Optional ByVal useEmbedded As Boolean = False) As PgpSecretKey
        If useEmbedded Then
            Using st As Stream = Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(GetAssemblyName() & ".MyKey - Private.asc")
                Dim bundle As PgpSecretKeyRingBundle = New PgpSecretKeyRingBundle(PgpUtilities.GetDecoderStream(st))
                For Each ring As PgpSecretKeyRing In bundle.GetKeyRings
                    For Each key As PgpSecretKey In ring.GetSecretKeys
                        If key.IsSigningKey Then Return key
                    Next
                Next
            End Using
        Else
            Using st As Stream = File.OpenRead(_mPrivateKeyPath)
                Dim bundle As PgpSecretKeyRingBundle = New PgpSecretKeyRingBundle(PgpUtilities.GetDecoderStream(st))
                For Each ring As PgpSecretKeyRing In bundle.GetKeyRings
                    For Each key As PgpSecretKey In ring.GetSecretKeys
                        If key.IsSigningKey Then Return key
                    Next
                Next
            End Using
        End If

        Return Nothing
    End Function

    Private Function ReadPrivateKey(ByVal keyId As Long, Optional ByVal useEmbedded As Boolean = False) As PgpPrivateKey
        If useEmbedded Then
            Using st As Stream = Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(GetAssemblyName() & ".MyKey - Private.asc")
                Dim bundle As PgpSecretKeyRingBundle = New PgpSecretKeyRingBundle(PgpUtilities.GetDecoderStream(st))
                Dim key As PgpSecretKey = bundle.GetSecretKey(keyId)
                If key Is Nothing Then Return Nothing
                Return key.ExtractPrivateKey(_mPassPhrase)
            End Using
        Else
            Using st As Stream = File.OpenRead(_mPrivateKeyPath)
                Dim bundle As PgpSecretKeyRingBundle = New PgpSecretKeyRingBundle(PgpUtilities.GetDecoderStream(st))
                Dim key As PgpSecretKey = bundle.GetSecretKey(keyId)
                If key Is Nothing Then Return Nothing
                Return key.ExtractPrivateKey(_mPassPhrase)
            End Using
        End If
    End Function

    Private Function GetAssemblyName() As String
        Dim names() As String = Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames
        If names.Length > 0 Then
            Return names(0).Split(".").First
        Else
            Return String.Empty
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Awesome!  Thanks so much for posting this - it worked pretty much out of the box.  The one change was `Org.BouncyCastle.OpenPgp.Utilities.IO.Streams.PipeAll(stUnc, stOut)` needed to be replaced by `Org.BouncyCastle.Utilities.IO.Streams.PipeAll(stUnc, stOut)`.